# Change the id of the selected <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have menu tab like this:

```
 <li><a id="current" href="Index.aspx">A</a></li>
 <li><a href="suppliers.aspx">B</a></li>
 <li><a href="RealWedding.aspx">C</a></li>
 <li><a href="About.aspx">D</a></li>
 <li><a href="ContactUs.aspx">E</a></li>
```

And the CSS is like this:

```
ul#minitabs a#current {
border-color: #EEACAC;
color:#AC2B53
}
```

How can I change the `id="current"` for the selected one, and not to be constant to the first one.

Comment: What do you mean by the selected one? The link will open a new page and will reset the JS

Comment: It would almost certainly be more appropriate to use classes instead of ids here. Switching ids seems like a bad idea.

Comment: I recoment you to use class instead off id. class="current"

Comment: What does "selected" mean? `:active`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will set `id` to `current` link based on what page is open. I think this is what you meant.

```
window.onload = function(){

  var url = window.location.href;
  url = url.split('/').pop();
  document.querySelector('a[href='+url+']').id="current";

};
```

Comment: This won't work for anything that is in a folder - for example, `<a href="/this/page.html">`.  Better to use `url = window.location.pathname;` to get the path of the current page, then you don't even need to split/pop.

Answer (score 0):

Improve this code. and use to change your classes or etc.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("a").click(function(){

            $(this).addClass('current');            
            console.log($(this).attr('class'));

        });

});
```

But I believe in CSS solution in you case.

a:hover{attr:attr}

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can keep up with the tab the user is clicking by doing:

```
$('li > a').on('click', function (e) {

    if (!$(this).hasClass('current')) {
        $('li > a').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
    }
    e.preventDefault();

});
```

We are checking to if the current a tag doesn't have the class 'current'.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3ebc7kx2/